# HVAC trying wire new thermostat old trane to new sensi smart touch

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat

My old trane thermostat b modle # 3AAT80B1A1 has wires

```
R red
T tan
O orange
G green
Y yellow
X2 Black
B blue
U green
W white
```

new thermostat has

```
RH power heating with jumper built in to
RC cooling
C common
G indoor blower
Y 1st outdoor stage cooling
Y2 2nd stage cooling
W/E first indoor stage heat
W2 2 stage heat
O/B change over reversing valve
L Heat pump system
```

Please let me know which wire to use and if any don't need to be used.

[image]
Here is the old thermostat and wiring.

[image]
This is the unit outside.

[image]
Here is the picture Unit Trane outside.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the thermostat and, more importantly, at the furnace/air-handler please?

Comment: PIictures are posted below

Comment: Do you not have a unit inside that has a bunch of ducts connected to it?

Comment: all the ducts are under the house

Comment: Then that's where you'll have to look for your air-handler or furnace then